# Generating a cookie from a site

Tags: go, cookies

The site I'm trying to generate a cookie for is giving it in this format through chrome:

```
isolate-web-session-id=5f943413-e947-45f9-9fee-78acfc0e8635 ( fake cookie)
```

My code is:

```golang
func main() {

    client := &http.Client{}

    /* Authenticate */
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "URL", nil)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error : %s", err)
    }
    jar := &myjar{}
    jar.jar = make(map[string][]*http.Cookie)
    client.Jar = jar
    /* Get Details */
    req.URL, _ = url.Parse("URL")
    resp, err = client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error : %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)

}

type myjar struct {
    jar map[string][]*http.Cookie
}

func (p *myjar) SetCookies(u *url.URL, cookies []*http.Cookie) {
    fmt.Printf("The URL is : %s\n", u.String())
    fmt.Printf("The cookie being set is : %s\n", cookies)
    p.jar[u.Host] = cookies
}

func (p *myjar) Cookies(u *url.URL) []*http.Cookie {
    fmt.Printf("The URL is : %s\n", u.String())
    fmt.Printf("Cookie being returned is : %s\n", p.jar[u.Host])
    return p.jar[u.Host]
}
```

Return is:

```
The URL is : URL
Cookie being returned is : []
&{200  200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Connection:[keep-alive] Content-Language:[zh-HK] Content-Type:[text/html;charset=UTF-8] Date:[Sat, 12 Mar 2022 16:52:05 GMT] Vary:[accept-encoding]] 0xc000388040 -1 [chunked] false true map[] 0xc000140000 0xc000124420}
```

I want to be able to generate a cookie that I can then use in the next request

Alternately I can run this code and get a cookie like this:

```
Cookie: 64304afb-250c-4922-8b9d-ad13f8f81deg ( fake cookie)
```

code:

```golang
    client := http.Client{}
    url := "URL"
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    finalcookiec := resp.Request.Response.Cookies()
    if finalcookiec == nil {
        return
    }
    //print finalcookiec
```

My end goal is to be able to generate a cookie in go then submit a post request and that be a valid cookie

Answer (score 0):

this is a sneak peek at this web [page](https://golangbyexample.com/cookies-golang/)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cookiejar"
)

var client http.Client

func init() {
    // jar has to be initialized, you dont have to nesscesary do it globally
    jar, err := cookiejar.New(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Got error while creating cookie jar %s", err.Error())
    }
    client = http.Client{
        Jar: jar,
    }
}

func main() {
    cookie := &http.Cookie{
        Name:   "token",
        Value:  "some_token",
        MaxAge: 300,
    }
    cookie2 := &http.Cookie{
        Name:   "clicked",
        Value:  "true",
        MaxAge: 300,
    }
    
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://google.com", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Got error %s", err.Error())
    }
    
    // important part, cookies should get printed
    req.AddCookie(cookie)
    req.AddCookie(cookie2)
    for _, c := range req.Cookies() {
        fmt.Println(c)
    }

    // Request is done trough client
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error occured. Error is: %s", err.Error())
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Printf("StatusCode: %d\n", resp.StatusCode)
}
```